# App not running in simulator : dyld`_dyld_debugger_notification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dyld, xcode13

every time I try to run the app in the simulator this bug appear, but when I try in real device it's works fine!

how to reproduce:
1- Run Xcode project
2- the app launch in the simulator and then the crash appear (only in simulators)

[crash appear in Xcode in running time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiHX7.png)

Xcode logs:

```
    dyld`_dyld_debugger_notification:
->  0x10d802a78 <+0>: pushq  %rbp
    0x10d802a79 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x10d802a7c <+4>: popq   %rbp
    0x10d802a7d <+5>: retq   
    0x10d802a7e <+6>: nop    
    0x10d802a7f <+7>: nop
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: there is no more data to provide only in image and here's it:
dyld`_dyld_debugger_notification:
->  0x10d802a78 <+0>: pushq  %rbp
    0x10d802a79 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x10d802a7c <+4>: popq   %rbp
    0x10d802a7d <+5>: retq   
    0x10d802a7e <+6>: nop    
    0x10d802a7f <+7>: nop

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: done, do I have to write more data!